# java desktop app invoking webservice on android app

Tags: java, android, web-services, sockets

I'm developing java desktop application that communicates with MySQL database via JDBC.
I want to develop an android application that will use Web services to access data in the same database.
Is there a way to tell android app from my desktop app when to invoke web service (I want all changes that i have committed from desktop app on database to show in android app)?

Which is the best way to implement this?

Is it possible to send parameters from desktop to android via socket and then in socket thread in android app to invoke web service? Is this good approach?

Answer (score 0):

the best way to do this is with an SOA approach.  use a j2ee container, and expose your services by web services.  then android can directly use those over http.

alternatively, you can use jdbc in android just as you use jdbc in the desktop application.

Comment: i want to use PHP web service from adroid app, but i'm looking for solution how to invoke that service automatically when i do some insertion in database from desktop app so that user can see changes on android app without manually refreshing (invoking web service).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html). GCM is perfect for doing this type of data syncing. To achieve that you can do the following

- Register your android app with the GCM server and save the ID in your database.
- Send a push notification from your desktop app or web service to your android app by taking the ID from your database at the time of update.
- Simply invoke the web service in your android app when you get the message from GCM server.

[Here](http://www.programming-techniques.com/2014/01/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-in-android.html) is an implementation of GCM server & client.

Comment: I forgot to mention that this apps will work in local network without internet connection.

Comment: In that case, either you can setup a local XMPP server for messaging or periodically check for updates from your android app's service.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to do, but the problem is that I'm looking for the best way to automatically call a web service from android app to get fresh data every time when make an insertion in the database from desktop app.